# Regarding WebTechnology concept in PHP

Tags: php, web-services

If i logged in the gmail,at the same time if i open orkut..it will automatically redirect to my orkut account.how can possible?

I have to implement same concept with the 2 domanis (ex: www.abc.com,www.bbc.com) throgugh PHP.

If i login into the www.abc.com, then if opened www.bbc.com in same browser ,it will takes to the users page in www.bbc.com (no need to ask for login in www.bbc.com).

and also

If i login into the www.bbc.com, then if opened www.abc.com in same browser ,it will takes to the users page in www.abc.com (no need to ask for login in www.abc.com).

Please help reagrding this...

regard
raju

Answer (score 0):

Frame the login window so that all your sites use login from the same site.

Comment: Use the <iframe> html tag. You need to host the login on one server. You cannot have an automatic login into a system, based on login from the other system, without connecting these two.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using third party cookies that allows communication between applications hosted on different domains.
http://www.opentracker.net/en/articles/all-about-cookies-third-party.jsp

This is not a definitive solution since third party cookies may be blocked by the browser.

You may also build an alternative by putting cross domains elements on your pages, such images with extra parameters in URL that may contains login of the user and a security token. Server B serving an image for user U connected to server A, may now consider that user U is connected.

Make sure to use a shared secret token between your applications for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you can also look into LDAP authentication using active directory